# Отрисовка полигона с помощью JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel

Нужно нарисовать полигон с кординнатами.
Проблема в том что открываеться окно но не отрисовывается полигон. Подскажите как решить данную проблему

```
public class PrintTest extends JPanel {
public void paint(Graphics2D g){
    int [] fillPolygon = new int[4];
    fillPolygon[0] = 14;
    fillPolygon[1] = 44;
    fillPolygon[2] = 34;
    fillPolygon[3] = 24;
    int [] ints = new int[4];
    ints[0] = 12;
    ints[1] = 72;
    ints[2] = 42;
    ints[3] = 52;
    g.fillPolygon(ints,fillPolygon,8);
}
```

}

```
public class Print {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Полигон");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    PrintTest test = new PrintTest();
    f.add(test);
    f.setSize(900,700);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: возможно потому, что не вызывается `pack()`. вызовите  `f.pack();`  перед  `f.setVisible(true);`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator само окно становиться маленьким и переноситься в левый верхний угол но полигона нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class PrintTest  extends JPanel {


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        int[] fillPolygon = new int[4];
        fillPolygon[0] = 14;
        fillPolygon[1] = 44;
        fillPolygon[2] = 34;
        fillPolygon[3] = 24;
        int[] ints = new int[4];
        ints[0] = 12;
        ints[1] = 72;
        ints[2] = 42;
        ints[3] = 52;
        g.drawPolygon(ints, fillPolygon, ints.length); // последний параметр неверно был задан 
    }
}


public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Полигон"); // создали фрейм 
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    PrintTest test = new PrintTest();

    f.setSize(900,700);
    f.add(test); // добавили наш 
    f.pack(); // собрали
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]