# Не отрисовывается изображение на JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Я пишу небольшую игру. Есть подставка, сверху падают предметы (овощи, фрукты и т.д). Саму логику игры еще до конца не реализовал. Несколько дней бился над одной и той же проблемой, облазил весь Гугл и Яндекс, но так и не нашел решение. Есть два объекта — Подставка, Картошка. Это изображения нарисованные на `JPanel`. Но почему-то вдвоем они на `JFrame`'е не отрисовываются. Только по отдельности. Мне нужно чтобы могли отрисовываться, позже я буду добавлять еще объекты, которые тоже должны отрисовываться. Прошу мне помочь.

**Game**

```
public class Game { // главный класс


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GetFruit");
        frame.setSize(700,500);
        Stand stand = new Stand();
        Potato potato = new Potato();
        frame.add(stand).setVisible(true);
        frame.add(potato).setVisible(true);
        KeyboardObserver observer = new KeyboardObserver(stand);
        frame.addKeyListener(observer);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

**Stand**

```
public class Stand extends JPanel { // Подставка
    private StandDirection direction;

    private BufferedImage image;


    public Stand(){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\images\\p.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Неверный путь к изображению.");
        }
    }

    public void setDirection(StandDirection direction) {
        this.repaint();
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public StandDirection getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    private int x = 250;
    private int y = 350;

    public void draw(){
        if (this.getDirection() == StandDirection.LEFT) {
            x -= 25;
            if(this.x <0 ){
                x+= 25;
            }
        } else if (this.getDirection() == StandDirection.RIGHT) {
            x += 25;
            if(this.x > 495){
                x -= 25;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw();
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

**Potato**

```
public class Potato extends JPanel{ // Картошка
    private BufferedImage image;

    private int x = (int)(Math.random() * 486); // генерируем случайный x
    private int y = 100;

    public Potato(){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\images\\potato.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Неверный путь к изображению.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,x,y,null);
        //y += 30;
        //this.repaint();
    }


}
```

**StandDirection**

```
public enum StandDirection { // enum со значениями подставки
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
```

**KeyboardObserver**

```
public class KeyboardObserver extends KeyAdapter { // Отслеживает нажатия клавиш
    private Stand stand;

    public KeyboardObserver(Stand stand) {
        this.stand = stand;
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            stand.setDirection(StandDirection.LEFT);
        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            stand.setDirection(StandDirection.RIGHT);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять немного логику смены места изображений (читай, панелей, на которых Вы нарисовали картошку и подставку).
В **Game** Вы создали панели, на которых нарисовали изображения.
Метод draw() перепишите, чтобы он в **Game** менял расположения панелей через

```
stand.setLocation(новый x, новый y)
```

и

```
potato.setLocation(новый x, новый y)
```

[Тут я пишу игру из Evoland2](https://github.com/PlemGitHub/Game-of-Cards/blob/master/src/threads/CardsMovementThr.java). Это класс, где именно так и двигаю карточки. Посмотрите метод run().

[Вытащил классы с залинкованного в коментариях гита на пасту](https://pastebin.com/J3QyhU4B)

Comment: Что я сделал: 
1. добавил метод draw в potato. 
2.В методах draw я вызываю this.setLocation(x,y)
Не помогает.  Мне кажется нужно сделать как-то по другому,тк основная проблема в том,что просто не хочет отрисовывать две панели,и я не понимаю почему. А сама логика вроде правильно реализована.

Comment: https://github.com/PlemGitHub/forMrKott сделал тут

Comment: все бы хорошо, НО , появилось 2 проблемы:
1. Метод draw() мне нужен чтобы подставка не выходила за пределы,а вы его убрали.
2.Метод setBounds() обрезает изображение,можно как-то сделать с setLocation() ?

Comment: ну я не планировал реализовывать все Ваши функции)
В KeyboardObserver делайте проверку на выход Х за края.
SetBounds используйте один раз, чтоб дать первоначальные Х и Y и задать размер панели под размер картинки, который вы знаете точно.

Comment: все, я разобрался,спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я еще почитал в гугле,у человека была похожая проблема. Но только с одной панелью.[Отрисовка полигона с помощью JPanel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621570/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jpanel?rq=1) . Он вызвал метод pack()  у фрейма. Когда я в своем проекте вызываю frame.pack(); окно становится маленьким и переносится в левый верхний угол экрана. Что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте после сборки `frame.pack()` написать `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` - должно помочь.